# C# nullable string error

Tags: c#, nullable

```
private string? typeOfContract
{
  get { return (string?)ViewState["typeOfContract"]; }
  set { ViewState["typeOfContract"] = value; }
}
```

Later in the code I use it like this:

```
typeOfContract = Request.QueryString["type"];
```

I am getting the following error at the declaration of `typeOfContract` line stating:

> The type 'string' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use
>   it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method
>   'System.Nullable<T>'

Any ideas? Basically, I want to make sure that `"type"` exists in the `QueryString` before performing an action.

Answer (score 303, accepted):

System.String is a reference type and already "nullable".

Nullable<T> and the ? suffix are for value types such as Int32, Double, DateTime, etc.

Comment: One thing to note: Nullable<T> is a value type itself, but the "struct" generic type constraint only includes non-nullable value types - so you can't do Nullable<Nullable<int>>.

Comment: In C# 8.0 reference types may be marked as nullable. One may type `string?` to tell the world this string may be null. Ref: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VdC0aoa7ung

Answer (score 38):

You are making it complicated. `string` is already nullable. You don't need to make it **more** nullable. Take out the `?` on the property type.

Comment: ... and a decade later, C# compiler now requires the `?` for nullable `string` properties when assigning it to `null`.

Answer (score 19):

string cannot be the parameter to Nullable because string is not a value type. String is a reference type.

```
string s = null;
```

is a very valid statement and there is not need to make it nullable.

```
private string typeOfContract
    {
      get { return ViewState["typeOfContract"] as string; }
      set { ViewState["typeOfContract"] = value; }
    }
```

should work because of the **as** keyword.

Answer (score 13):

String is a reference type, so you don't need to (and cannot) use `Nullable<T>` here. Just declare typeOfContract as string and simply check for null after getting it from the query string. Or use String.IsNullOrEmpty if you want to handle empty string values the same as null.

Answer (score 4):

For nullable, use `?` with all of the **C# primitives**, except for string.

The following page gives a list of the **C# primitives**:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711900(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Thanks Mina, I found a different link and updated the reference.

Comment: Not just primitives, all non-nullable value types (that aren't handled specially by the .NET) work.