# Why is string nullable?

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The type ‘string’ must be a non-nullable type in order to use it as parameter T in the generic type or method ‘System.Nullable<T>’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236468/the-type-string-must-be-a-non-nullable-type-in-order-to-use-it-as-parameter-t)

As the title says, why are strings nullable by default in C#, but if I want, say, ints or doubles to be null, I have to explicitly say so?

Comment: because a string is a reference type.

Comment: @JW. - I don't think the questions are the same. This is far more general then the proposed duplicate.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because string is a reference type, deriving from `object` and [most] other default types are value types, deriving implicitly from System.ValueType;

Comment: +1. "deriving from `struct`" is not exactly true - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch(v=vs.100).aspx :  "All value types are derived implicitly from the System.ValueType."

Comment: And [ValueType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype.aspx) also derives from object, but that doesn't mean it is a reference type.  Your statement is mostly accurate but I'd consider rewording a little

Comment: Good points, the provided link is certainly more complete than my one-liner.

Comment: This isn't a good answer. It is merely stating the obvous. WE KNOW IT'S A REFERENCE TYPE, WE WANT TO KNOW WHY! I get that in C++ string is a class and not a primitive but C# is NOT C++ and has many differences (including how it handles 'primitives'). So why not handle string as a Value Type and not a Reference Type?

Comment: @psubsee2003 The class `System.ValueType` itself is a reference type. For example you can say `ValueType vt1 = null;` or `ValueType vt2 = DateTime.Now; /* boxing */`. But `DateTime` is an example of a value type.