# Set a string column to nullable in EF6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a model that i created it bu EF6:

```
public partial class Comment
{
    [DisplayName("شناسه نظر")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "متن نظر را وارد کنید")]
    [DisplayName("متن نظر")]
    public string CommentText { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("تعداد پسندیدن ")]
    public long LikeCount { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("تعداد نپسندیدن")]
    public long DisLikeCount { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("تاریخ انتشار ")]
    public System.DateTime PublishDate { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("وضعیت نمایش ")]
    public string Visible { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("نام کاربری ")]
    public Nullable<string> AutherUserName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("شناسه نظراصلی")]
    public Nullable<int> CommentFKId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("شناسه کاربر")]
    public Nullable<int> StudentId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("شناسه محتوا ")]
    public Nullable<int> ContentId { get; set; }

    public virtual Comment Comments { get; set; }
    public virtual Comment Comment1 { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
    public virtual Content Content { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see i have several **Nullable** int columns in my model ,But i can't set a string column to null :

```
public Nullable<string> AutherUserName { get; set; }
```

And I got this error :

> The type 'string' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Nullable'

I am working with MVC4

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236468/the-type-string-must-be-a-non-nullable-type-in-order-to-use-it-as-parameter-t

Comment: If you want to have null in string even if your ui gives a blank you could do this in the setter of the property.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Strings are reference types, so are already "nullable". Only value types (such as int) can be nullable as they can't otherwise be null.

Comment: So you mean if the textbox of my column be empty it is going to be Null?

Comment: If the value of the string property on the model is null, then it will be null yes.  If it was "blank" (the empty string), then it wouldn't be null.  For a string column to be non-nullable, you'd use the [Required] attribute as well.

Comment: Any advice if my Database-first `not-null` design produced a class with a plain `string` property? It did not include [Required] attribute, but in its ModelBuilding, it presumably established that the column was `not-null`; is there a fluid way to ensure the property is `null`? And change it if it's not?