# Writing Nullable value with BinaryWriter

Tags: c#, nullable, binarywriter, non-nullable

I want to write a nullable string to file using `BinaryWriter` and this code:

```
  BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(st);
  String? s;
  if(s!=null){
        writer.Write(s);
    }
```

but this error occurs:

> The type 'string' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Nullable'

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/187406/700972

Comment: oh, silly question I forgotten that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings can always be null, you don't need to try and make it nullable as they're not value types. Just remove the ? That makes it nullable to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Strings are already nullable in C#.NET, they're a reference type with syntactic sugar around them to make them easier to use. You can't make a nullable double nullable, the universe would collapse.

Answer (score 2):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) documentation, we can see that Nullable type can be used only with structs:

```
[SerializableAttribute]
public struct Nullable<T>
where T : struct
```

p.s. see also [Constraints on Type Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

String is a reference type. It can not be nullable.
`public struct Nullable<T> where T : struct, new()`