# Nullable for ORM Objects

Tags: c#, orm, nullable

Based on reading [Nullable Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), I understand that it's proper to use `Nullable` for a primitive type that may be null in a database.

Is it necessary to use the `?` (Nullable) type for objects?

Example:

```
public DateTime? DateCreated {get; set; }
```

or

```
 public DateTime DateCreated {get; set; }
```

Comment: Correction: it's proper to use `Nullable<T>` for a value type that may be null in the database. That includes, among others, `DateTime` (and `DateTimeOffset`).

Answer (score 1):

Your example is correct. You will need `DateTime?` to have the ORM (say NH) treat it as a nullable type. For objects you dont need to put the question mark.

Also, on a side-note, the question mark T? is an alias for `Nullable<T>`. The compiler will translate the `T?` to `Nullable<T>`. You can check this on the debugger if you want a proof :)

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `Nullable<T>` is valid as DateTime is not a reference type. However, for objects (and types derived from object), you cannot use `Nullable<T>` as the compiler will throw an error; see: [C# nullable string error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187406/c-sharp-nullable-string-error)