# Class of type <T> with nullable value of Type<T>

Tags: c#, generics, nullable

I have the need to make a class that can hold the value for the following types:  `int?, decimal?, date, bool? string`.

I want to be able to do soemthing like:

```
var x = new MyClass<int?>()  
x.Value = null;
x.value = 99;         

// or

var y = new MyClass<bool?>();
y.Value = null;
y.Value = true

// and so on
```

I have been trying to create a class of type T along the lines of:

```
public class TestClass<T>
{             
    public T? Value{ get; set; }
}
```

I want to use Value to take any of the allowed types but I can't make T nullable.  The error is:

> Only non nullable value type could be underlying of Sysytem.Nullable

is there anyway of doing what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: Please see the answer in the post "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187406/c-sharp-nullable-string-error/54878479#54878479". In upcoming version of c# 8, reference types are non nullable by default.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class TestClass<T> where T : struct
{             
    public T? Value{ get; set; }
}
```

Classes cannot be nullable as class is a reference type. You have to add constraint to your generic class to allow only structs (which can be nullable).

`string` is a reference type and your class won't work with `string` it this case as it can't be nullable.

Comment: thanks.  so is it possible to use the same class with value and reference types like: var y = new TestClass<string> or new TestClass<int?>?

Comment: It is possible as long as you are not trying to force them to be nullable by writing `public T? Value{ get; set; }`

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you are passing a nullable into your generic, and then trying to make *it* nullable.

Try this:

```
public class TestClass<T>
{             
    public T Value{ get; set; }
}
```

Now when you do this:

```
var x = new MyClass<int?>();
```

Value will be defined as `int?` so you can use it in the way you want. If you define it as

```
var x = new MyClass<int>();
```

Value will be defined as `int` - and won't accept nulls.

Comment: must just be me, but this doesn't work in any scenario i've tried, still throws an exception :-(

Comment: Sorry, copied the code for expediency and modified - unfortunately I copied from gzaxx's post rather than davy's. Corrected the issue.